# Removing strings from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to work on a method that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and removes all the strings of even length from it.  This is what I have so far:

```
public void removeEvenLength(ArrayList<String> items) {
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.length() % 2 == 0) items.remove(s);
    }
}
```

For some reason this is not working, it shows an error when I try to run it on any ArrayList with elements in it.  Could someone tell me why?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It’s dangerous to remove items from a list while iterating over it.  Try to use a `while` loop and an `Iterator` (`items.iterator()`). Then call the `iterator.remove()` method to remove the current item.

Comment: Any time you're asking about an error, *for the love of Zeus post the error*.  In this case it's obvious what's wrong but it is universally a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove items from `List` and at the same time run in loop. Use `iterator` for that.

```
List<String> items = ....
Iterator<String> it = items.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   String s = it.next(); 
    if (s.length() % 2 == 0){
         it.remove();
     }

}
```

Comment: Actually I can use loops and remove items from list. Problem is only with enhanced for loop which creates its own iterator which notices when list has been modified and throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the long-winded idiom:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = items.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
  if (it.next().length() % 2 == 0) it.remove();
```

Reason: your *enhanced for* loop compiles into just such code as above and, while you are using an `Iterator`, you are not allowed to change the underlying list by any other route except by calling `Iterator#remove`, so that the iterator is aware of the removal.

Comment: I like your way with 2 rows but how would I debug it?

Comment: I don't use the debugger so I'm not used to adapting code to that concern. If I ever have a stacktrace issue with such code, then I temporarily split the line. You can do the same to debug. BTW in reality I'd use a single line for that code, I've split it only due to the constraints of the SO code box :)

Comment: Firstly, choosing short code over readability is most of the time not useful, just to mention my opinion. And secondly, you forgot the second semicolon in the for loop.

Comment: @Pr0gr4mm3r I choose readability, that's why I place the code on a single line. That way it reads more fluently like an English sentence.  Also, compact code means seeing more code at once in a single screen, which is very important to me when trying to keep a lot of code in focus at once. Feel free to have different reading skills than me. Oh, and many thanks for the missing semicolon.

Comment: It's not a problem of how different our reading skills are. It's basicly just a problem how we define readability. But this is just offtopic and has nothing to do with the question itself, so lets quit this.